# Perl: apply regular expressions in sequence

Tags: regex, perl, text-extraction

I need help in writing a Perl one-liner to

1. find a string in a file and
2. extract a floating point or an exponent number from that string.

For example, I have a text file called `results.log`:

```
...
TOL: 0.0244141
ort: 0.000282395
Q orthogonality: True

EPS: 0.000488281
err: 9.58692e-05
QR decomposition: True

Success: True
...
```

It contains results of a numerical experiment. I would like to find a line that starts with `TOL:` and extract the tolerance value `0.0244141`. I can write a one-liner to find a line starting with `TOL`:

```
perl -ne '/TOL:/ && print' results.log
TOL: 0.0244141
```

I can find a line containing the floating point number `0.0244141`

```
echo "TOL: 0.0244141" | perl -ne '/\d+.\d+/ && print'
```

Is there a way to "stack" two regular expressions together and apply them in sequence one after another to extract the numerical value itself? In other words, is it possible to apply a regular expression onto a result of a preceding regular expression?

To complete the task I would like to call this one-liner from a Perl script and store the extracted result into a variable:

```
my $tol = system( qq{ perl -ne '... && print' results.log } );
```

Comment: This is like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) wrapped inside an XY-problem. ;) Calling a Perl one-liner from inside Perl might be considered somewhat odd. You can just use regular code to accomplish the same thing with less problems. And also, `system()` does not return output, you need `qx()` or backticks.

Comment: I fully agree with your comment. But I think it is an overkill to do it in a regular code manner (open a file, parse it and close a file) in order to find a single value. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, that IS what you are doing... but you are doing it more slowly, and more complicated and error prone.

Comment: I see. Could you please show me a better way to do it from a script, a proper Perl way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice and flexible solution is to read the values into a hash, then you can use values as you please.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $log = "results.log";
open my $fh, "<", $log or die "Cannot open $log: $!";
my %log;     # declare variable to store values

while (<$fh>) {   # while we can read a line from the file
    chomp;        # remove newline
    my ($key, $val) = split / *: */, $_, 2;   # split the line on :, also remove whitespace
    next unless defined $val;     # skip lines which do not contain values
    $log{$key} = $val;            # store the value in the appropriate key
}

print $log{TOL};    # <--- value is in $log{TOL}
```

All of the values from the file are stored in `%log`. Of course, if you are just interested in the TOL value, you can just do

```
my $tol;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/^TOL: (.+)/) {
        $tol = $1;
        last;              # skip to end
    }
}
```

The benefit compared to not using a shell call is that it is faster and easier to error control.

Comment: Can you please explain, what does `my %log;` do and happens in the `while` loop in the first code snippet?

Comment: `my` just declares a variable. I added comments to explain.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you only need to concatenate the regexes you already got:

```
perl -ne '/TOL: (\d+.\d+)/ && print $1 . "\n"' results.log
```

Output:

```
0.0244141
```

The parentheses makes it capture everything that matches within. Each pair of `(` ... `)` assigns what's being matched to a new numbered variabe. `$1` for the first match, `$2` for the second etc.

More on that topic: [Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups)

---

If you want this as a part of an existing perl script, don't use `system()` to start yet another perl interpreter. Just open the file from within the existing script. Here's an example where I've put that in a `sub` routine.

```
sub print_TOL {
    # extract the first argument to the function
    my $filename = shift;

    # open the file - or `die` with an error message
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$0: ERROR: $filename: $!";

    # read line by line from the file into $_
    while(<$fh>) {
        if( /TOL: (\d+.\d+)/ ) {  # same match as before
            print $1 . "\n";
            # If you only want to print the first match, use "last;" here.
            #last;  
        }
    }
}

print_TOL 'results.log';
```

Comment: Yes, I only need the number. Can you please explain the second command in detail? I don't understand the parentheses and the use of `$1`. How are these concepts called in Perl? If possible, would you please direct me to a resource, where I could read about them? Thank you!

Comment: @mabalenk You're welcome! I added an explanation and the link to the perldoc page with more info. Hope it made it a little clearer.

Comment: What do parameters `. "\n"` do? The command seems to work without them.

Comment: @mabalenk It adds a newline to the end of every printed line. If you get more than one match in the file they would otherwise be printed after each other on the same line.

Comment: He is printing a newline so as to not screw up your prompt if you are testing the command in a terminal. You can accomplish the same by using the `-l` switch.